# Finite-dimensional compact groups

Tags: lie-groups, compactness, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a compact connected metrizable group of finite topological dimension. Is $G$ a Lie group? Or what should be equivalent in this case, does it have a faithful finite-dimensional representation?

This is something that should be well known, but it is difficult to find.

Comment: The book [From groups to geometry and back](https://books.google.at/books?id=E5OjDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&dq=Let+G++be+a+compact+connected+metrizable+group+of+finite+topological+dimension.+Is+G+a+linear+group?&source=bl&ots=I8qXFP7XGK&sig=ACfU3U0YlvV11tSxZjAdBg9LQ9GLjq0Cvg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMwKHDwfbnAhXMTcAKHQcpBuAQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Let%20G%20%20be%20a%20compact%20connected%20metrizable%20group%20of%20finite%20topological%20dimension.%20Is%20G%20a%20linear%20group%3F&f=false) has some results, e.g., the theorem by Montgomery-Zippin, which might help.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks! Montgomery-Zippin should imply that when $G$ is also locally connected, then - since it acts transitively in itself - it is a Lie group. Since conversely a compact connected Lie group is locally connected, my question now boils down to the problem whether there is a compact connected finite-dimensional metrizable group which is not locally connected.

Comment: @user446046 About "what should be equivalent": it's indeed equivalent: E. Cartan's theorem that every closed subgroup of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ is a Lie group, ensures that if a compact group has a faithful continuous finite-dim rep, then it's a Lie group, and the Peter-Weyl theorem ensures that compact groups have faithful finite-dimensional reps with arbitrary small kernel, and in particular compact Lie groups have faithful ones.

Comment: About your comment: it's not true that a compact locally connected group is Lie: a counterexample is $(\mathrm{R}/\mathbf{Z})^I$ for $I$ infinite: it is not even locally contractible. Still it's true for *finite-dimensional* compact groups.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the example, I implicitly included to the assumptions in the comment above the finite-dimensionality, as in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. As an example, consider a [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)) $G$, which is the inverse limit of, say, $2$-fold covering maps of circles
$$
... \to S^1\to S^1\to S^1. 
$$
This topological group has topological dimension 1, is metrizable, compact, connected, even abelian, but is not a Lie group (it is not locally connected). The local model for this group is the product of a Cantor set with an interval.